# Restart Activity with onResume method

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to restart an activitiy with the onResume() method. I thought i can use an Intent to achieve that, but that ends in an endless loop.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Is there another way to restart an activity?

Comment: The code you have written is a recursive loop yes. OnResume triggers for new intents too. What is is you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would question why you want to do this... but here is the first thing that popped into my mind:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Log.v("Example", "onCreate");
    getIntent().setAction("Already created");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.v("Example", "onResume");

    String action = getIntent().getAction();
    // Prevent endless loop by adding a unique action, don't restart if action is present
    if(action == null || !action.equals("Already created")) {
        Log.v("Example", "Force restart");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    // Remove the unique action so the next time onResume is called it will restart
    else
        getIntent().setAction(null);

    super.onResume();
}
```

You should make `"Already created"` unique so that no other Intent might accidentally has this action.

Comment: yeah...when the activity restarts, onResume will be called again... and then the activity will restart... and then onResume will be called again.  Not sure what this user is attempting but it won't work.

Comment: @user1627867 I updated my answer. The first version caused the app to restart twice, this new version works as expected.

Comment: its is in a loop. oops

2019-10-30 13:07:19.304 26192-26192/com.example.android.appusagestatistics I/lifeCycle: in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your onResume()

`@Override
protected void onResume() {
    recreate();
}`