# Back to MainActivity after wake from sleep

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume

I am new to Android, and I want my mobile app back to MainActivity after wake from sleep instead of staying in the page it slept.

Do i need to add new intent code in every activity of the onResume? or i can use the noHistory attribute to handle this???

Comment: you may try this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146593/3839235

Comment: Yes, you need to overide onResume function in every activity.

Comment: But i would like to ask these app like facebook and instagram, the activity will "re-launch" after several time. Is that destroy by system or by the onResume code?