# Refreshing parent activity on going back from current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to refresh the contents of the previous activity when i am going back from current activity to the just previous or parent activity. How to do this?

Comment: You need to read about [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Or you can restart activity like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146522/restart-activity-with-onresume-method

Comment: in onbackpressed call intent instead finish() of activity ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the child activity the original activity will receive a call to `onSaveInstanceState`.  It can save any information it needs to in the `Bundle` passed to that call.

When the Parent activity is restarted, the `Bundle` created by `onSaveInstanceState` will be passed to the Activities `onCreate` method which can use the information as necessary to put the Activity back into the desired state.

This `Bundle` will also be passed to the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method of the parent activity so you may wish to use the data there instead.

To read more about this in the Android documentation, take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

If the Parent activity needs to change state as a result of actions in the child Activity it can implement `onActivityResult` to receive the data passed back by the child activity as described on [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from question what kind of data you have. You can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on Ui thread inside onResume() to refresh data.